# Problem generate new component -> Angular cli

Tags: angular

I have this problem ng generate app1/probangif An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "app1/probangif" not found in collection "@ngrx/schematics"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify what you want to generate after 'generate':
ng generate module 'name of module'

or for a new project:

ng new 'name of project'

Learn to google stuff, you'll need to, everyone does. waiting for answers on stackoverflow hinders your ability to be productive. Cheers.

Comment: More of a comment rather than an answer

Comment: How so? It solved his problem, didn't it?